# PostgreSQL: Insert with mutual FK dependency

Tags: postgresql

I'm struggling with this particular issue, I have the following tables, please see the columns and their properties:

### User

**id [pk]**
status
user
password
contact [fk]
created_log [fk]

---

### Creation_Log

id [pk]
**user [fk]**
created_on

---

Please notice the User.user and the Creation_Log.user, to make an insert into User, the check validation for the FK of creation_log is restricting me from doing it, and the same if I go to Creation_Log and try to generate a new one, it'll ask me for the User.

Is there anyway I can turn the checks off to create at least one admin user?

Comment: Remove `created_log [fk]` from table `user`, it is useless and even harmful.

Comment: You mean leave the column, but delete the FK?

Comment: Remove the column, you do not need it.

Comment: Then how can I have a log of the creations/modifications of every single table?, what I wanted to do is instead of declaring CreatedOn, and CreatedBy columns in every single table, just have a separated one and maintain it there

Comment: The foreign key `user` in `creation_log` unambiguously references the user. If you want to list entries from `creation_log` for a given user: `select * from user u left join creation_log c on u.id = c.user`.